# How to extract data from JSON - Laravel & JSON

Tags: php, json, laravel

This is how my json looks like `["Chicken",{"quantity":"1"},"Froggies",{"quantity":"2"},"Fryies",{"quantity":"3"}].`

Is there a way that i can get the data out the results like

`Chicken : 1`, `Froggies:2`, `Fryies:3`

I tried to use implode to get this done but i get an error saying `array to string conversion`,

Below is my code

```
 foreach($request->get('item_id') as $key => $id) 
  {

      $selected_item = Item::all()->where('id',$id);

      foreach($selected_food as $select)
      {
         $food_selected[]= $select->name ;

         $food_selected[] = ['quantity' => $request->get('quantity')[$key]];

      }          
  }  

       $query ="Your items are ".implode(',',$food_selected)."";
```

Comment: try `json_decode($food_selected);`

Comment: @urfusion "json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given"

Comment: What is the output of `echo "<pre>"; print_r($food_selected);`

Comment: @urfusion, i get exactly what i have in the question `["Chicken",{"quantity":"1"},"Froggies",{"quantity":"2"},"Fryies",{"quantity":"3"}]`

Comment: @urfusion, so  i did this  `json_decode($food_selected[0]) ` but then it returns empty

Comment: Your json seems fine to me, `json_decode($food_selected,true);`.

One more thing, is it your full response? if not, check the json for valid on http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Yes it is my full response

Comment: Does `$request->get('item_id')` contains more than one IDs?

Comment: @Konafets, yes it can contain more than one id

Comment: @urfusion, yes i just checked. it says valid json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe array of objects would be more useful in that situation, which you could get this way:

```
$arr = [];

foreach ( $request->get('item_id') as $key => $id ) {

    $selected_item = Item::all()->where('id', $id);

    foreach ( $selected_item as $select ) {// $selected_item or $selected_food here
        /*
        $obj = new stdClass;

        $obj->{$select->name} = $request->get('quantity')[$key];

        $arr[] = $obj;*/

        $arr[$select->name] = (int) $request->get('quantity')[$key];
    }          
}

$query = '';

foreach ( $arr as $k => $v ) {
    $query .= ' '.$k.': '.$v.',';
}

$query = rtrim($query, ',');

$query = ltrim($query);

$query = "Your items are ".$query;
```

Comment: In the string, i get Your items are [{"name":"Friens","quantity":"1"},{"name":"Chicken,"quantity‌​":"1"}]. How can i do like Fries:1, Chicken:1

Comment: Edited. Try now.

Comment: Okay now this is now is like `[{"Chicken":"3"},{"Fries":"2"}].. I don't need the `brackets` and the `"`
`

Comment: Now? (11 more to go...)

Comment: Now, it is like  `{"Tilapia":3,"Cheese Balls":2}`

Comment: Write in your question (or here) how exactly - not just partially - you want output to be. Like what should string variable `$query` looks like.

Comment: I have already written that like 3 times in the comment and already in the question. Maybe you didn't see that. If you look in the question i have this there  `Chicken : 1, Froggies:2, Fryies:3` . They must have no `brackets` and `"`

Comment: I am not sure where we (you) are going with this but try now.

Comment: Enjoy and be more focused on data structure than output presentation. ;)

Comment: You mean your structure is not standard?

Comment: I mean what you wanted is just a string. Same string you could extract from array and object I wrote first time. And for data structure I would go with object that can be passed as well organized JSON to AJAX when/if needed. `{"chicken": 3, "fries": 1}`. That's why I left block of code commented out. There is also an issue with spaced words as name and you need to think how to handle those. But I am glad you have got wanted result.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the ID is unique key for an Item and your `Item::all()->where('id',$id)` will return only one record. If this is true, the second loop is unnecessary.

Based on this assumption, I come to this code:

```
$result = collect($request->get('item_id'))
            ->map(function($itemId, $itemKey) use ($request) {
              $item = Item::find($itemId);

             return $item->name . ' : ' . $request->get('quantity')[$itemKey];
          })->implode(',');

// $result contains the string: "Chicken : 2, Fries : 1"
```

For explanation:

1. Cast the array into a collection
2. Use map to loop over it
3. Find the Item by its ID
4. Return the name and the quantity (this returns a collection)
5. Implode the collection